# How do I get the MySQL Connector/NET driver version programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Is there an easy way to get the version of the MySQL driver programmatically from within a C# program referencing MySQL.Data.dll ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
Version version = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MySQL.Data.dll").Version;
```

Depending on where your referenced mysql.data assembly lives, you may need to prepend a path to the dll file name.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the assembly full name to get the version of your .net connector and then use the table you can find here (chapter one) : http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-net-en.a4.pdf to see which Mysql Server version are supported.